# Scrolls only once 'var distance' in a div with overflow: auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, overflow

So I have the issue with scrolling.

Using: `jquery.mousewheel.min.js`

There is a `div` with `overflow: auto` and it has fixed width or height 600px.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

    function wheel(event) {
        var delta = 0;
        if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
        else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

        handle(delta);
        if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = false;
    }

    function handle(delta) {
        var time = 200;
        var distance = 300;
        $('#blablabla').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $(window).scrollLeft() - (distance * delta)
        }, time);

        $('#lolololol').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
        }, time);
    }           
});
```

The issue:
Content inside that `div` scrolls only once 300px left or right / up or down and no more.
Without this script, `overflow: auto` works fine. Need to make this work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are animating the scroll of the div, but using the window's scroll as a parameter value on the animate. Use the div's own scroll value.

For example, change this:

```
    $('#lolololol').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time);
```

to this:

```
    $('#lolololol').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $('#lolololol').scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time);
```

I've created a fiddle simulating your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/9dNGL/2/